# Can it be shown that $A*B/\langle\langle A \rangle\rangle \cong B$ without referencing a specific construction of A*B?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $A$ and $B$ be groups and $A*B$ the free product. Let $N=\langle\langle A \rangle\rangle$ be the smallest normal subgroup of $A*B$ containing $A$. Show that $A*B/N \cong B$ without utilizing a specific construction of the free product. That is, formulate a proof without explicitly examining the elements of $A*B$.

For a homework assignment I turned in last week, I was asked to show that $A*B/N \cong B$, which I did by showing that every element $Na_1b_1\cdots a_nb_n \in A*B/N$ is of the form $Nb$ for some $b\in B$ and then by defining $\phi:A*B/N \to B$ as $\phi(Na_1b_1\cdots a_nb_n)=\phi(Nb)=b$, which can fairly easily be shown to be an isomorphism. While this sufficed for the assignment, I don't particularly like this proof.

I'm interested in knowing if it can be shown that $A*B/N \cong B$ without reference to the elements or specific construction of $A*B$. That is, does $A*B/N \cong B$ follow from the universal property of the free product or related theorems? All of my attempts so far have been fruitless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me give a general categorical version of this statement and then prove it.

> **Theorem**: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with a zero object and suppose $A$ and $B$ be objects of $\mathcal{C}$ which have a coproduct $A*B$.  Let $p:A*B\to B$ be the map induced by the identity $B\to B$ and the zero map $A\to B$ (i.e., the unique map that factors through a zero object).  Then $p$ is a coequalizer of the inclusion $i:A\to A*B$ and the zero map $0:A\to A*B$ (that is, $p$ is a cokernel of $i$).

*Proof*:  By definition of $p$, $pi$ is the zero map $A\to B$, and $p0$ is also the zero map $A\to B$, so $pi=p0$.  Now suppose $q:A*B\to C$ is such that $qi=q0$.  Let $f=qj:B\to C$ where $j:B\to A*B$ is the inclusion. Then $$fpi=f0=0=q0=qi$$ (here I abuse notation and write $0$ for any zero map) and $$fpj=f1_B=f=qj.$$  Since $A*B$ is a coproduct with inclusions $i$ and $j$, this implies $fp=q$, so $q$ factors through $p$.  Moreover, the factorization is unique, since if $f'pj=qj$ then $f'=qj$ (since $pj=1_B$).

In the case of groups, the statement that $p$ is the coequalizer of $i$ and $0$ says exactly that a map on $A*B$ factors (uniquely) through $p$ iff $A$ is contained in its kernel.  This is exactly the universal property of the quotient of $A*B$ by the normal subgroup generated by $A$, so this says $B\cong A*B/N$.

Comment: perhaps you can *explicitly* indicate how your reply solves the given question; that is, how $A*B / <<A>> \cong B$ is proven with your formulation.

Comment: I have added a final paragraph about that.

Comment: Thank-you; I think such a little piece is important to tie matters together :-)

Comment: Thanks for that last paragraph of clarification, I'm still really new to category theory, so sometimes the language can get overwhelming. Having a way to tie it all back to things I know is really helpful.